# float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType' is my error? is my argument wrong?

Tags: python

```
float(first) == print("enter first num :")
operator == print("enter operator (+,-,*,/,%) : ")
float(second) == print("enter second num : ")``
    
if operator == "+":
    print(first + second)
        
elif operator == "-":
    print(first - second)
        
elif operator == "*":
    print(first * second)
        
elif operator == "/":
    print(first / second)
        
elif operator == "%":
    print(first % second)
        
else:
    print("invalid operation")
```

Comment: `first = float(input("enter first num :"))`

Comment: print only DISPLAY stuff, it doesn't read anything